# xv_11_laser_driver build error

Tags: ros, xv-11-laser-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very new to ROS and Linux in general but have worked through the introductory tutorials. I followed the xv_11_laser_driver tutorial but it failed during the build.

First, a basic question: I have loaded ROS Indigo but the xv_11 tutorial is for  cturtle. I did use Indigo in the rosinstall step. Is this going to be an issue? I especially wonder about the different build systems used.

The actual error statements are:

```
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:847 (message):
  [rosboost-cfg --libs system] failed with error: Traceback (most recent call
  last):

    File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in <module>
      rosboost_cfg.main()
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 359, in main
      output = lflags(ver, options.lflags.split(','))
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 278, in lflags
      s += lib_flags(ver, lib) + " "
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 268, in lib_flags
      lib = find_lib(ver, name)
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 238, in find_lib
      raise BoostError('Could not locate library [%s], version %s'%(name, ver))

  rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Could not locate library [system],
  version (1, 54, 0, '/usr', '/usr/include', True, True)"

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (rosbuild_link_boost)
```

I do not have a clue on where to start fixing this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187492/xv_11_laser_driver-build-error/) by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like rosbuild is having a hard time finding the required boost libraries on Indigo.

I've filed a bug about this here: https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/62

In the meantime, you may want to look for a catkinized version of the xv11 driver, and try that on Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-23**:
The bug is fixed in the upcoming version 1.11.4 of ros-indigo-ros. Thanks for the report.

**Comment by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on 2014-07-23**:
Thanks for the quick responses.

When will 1.11.4 be available and how can I track its availability?

I am a long time developer just new to ROS and Linux. Is there a patch I can do to make the build work, i.e. change where the script is looking for ros-boost? I will look for it but...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-23**:
You will find the patch in the ticket reference above (actually in this pull request: https://github.com/ros/ros/pull/63/files ).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-07-23**:
The Debian package build progress can be tracked here: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=rosboost_cfg

Usually it takes a day to rebuild and being available in ros-shadow-fixed. When ever it is synced to public an email is send to the ros-users mailing list. It might take several days (sometimes even longer if some packages are building successfully).

**Comment by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on 2014-07-24**:
Again, appreciate the quick response. I got it to build and, following the rest of the tutorial, can see my office in rviz!